# I'm making a list view that retrieves names of faculties from my database and display it on the list view

Tags: php, android, listview

I'm getting the exception error through Toast as "Error..2 JSONException: Value  of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject".
Please suggest a solution!

IT_Faculty.java

```
    package com.roadraz.vcademy1;

    import android.app.ListActivity;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
    import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
    import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;

    public class IT_Faculty extends AppCompatActivity {

        private String jsonResult;
        private String url = "<have added my server address>";
        private ListView listView;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_it__faculty);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.faculty_listView);
            accessWebService();
        }

        private class JsonReadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
                try {
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    jsonResult = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
                String rLine = "";
                StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                try {
                    while ((rLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                        answer.append(rLine);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    //e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(IT_Faculty.this, "Error...1" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return answer;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                ListDrawer();
            }
        }//end async task

        public void accessWebService() {
            JsonReadTask task = new JsonReadTask();
            task.execute(new String[]{url});
        }

        //build hash set for list view
        public void ListDrawer() {
            List<Map<String, String>> facultyList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
            try {
                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
                JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("asdb");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
                    String name = jsonChildNode.optString("name");
                    String number = jsonChildNode.optString("roll_no");
                    String outPut = name + "-" + number;
                    facultyList.add(createFaculty("faculties",outPut));
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Toast.makeText(IT_Faculty.this, "Error...2" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter= new SimpleAdapter(IT_Faculty.this,facultyList,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,new String[]{"faculties"},new int[]{android.R.id.text1});
            listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
            Toast.makeText(IT_Faculty.this, "c", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        private HashMap<String,String> createFaculty(String name,String roll_no){
            HashMap<String,String> facultyNameNo=new HashMap<String,String>();
            facultyNameNo.put(name,roll_no);
            return facultyNameNo;
        }
    }
```

it__faculty.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_it__faculty" tools:context="com.roadraz.vcademy1.IT_Faculty">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/faculty_listView">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.roadraz.vcademy1" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".FirstPage"
            android:label="V-Cademy"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".IT_Faculty"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_it__faculty"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

faculty_fetch.php

```
<?php
$host="localhost";
$username="myusername";
$password="mypassword";
$db_name="asdb";    
$con=mysql_connect("$host","$username","$password");
mysql_select_db=("$db_name");
$sql="select * from asdb where class='Faculty'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$json=array();

if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
$json['asdb']['sr_no']=$row['sr_no']
$json['asdb']['name']=$row['name']
$json['asdb']['email']=$row['email']
$json['asdb']['roll_no']=$row['roll_no']
$json['asdb']['class']=$row['class']
$json['asdb']['phone']=$row['phone']
$json['asdb']['password']=$row['password'];
}
}
mysql_close($con);
echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

Here's the Android Monitor

```
03-25 01:43:08.802 28804-28804/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
03-25 01:43:08.802 28804-28804/? I/art: Late-enabling JIT
03-25 01:43:08.810 28804-28804/? I/art: JIT created with code_cache_capacity=2MB compile_threshold=1000
03-25 01:43:08.922 28804-28804/com.roadraz.vcademy1 W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.roadraz.vcademy1-1/lib/x86
03-25 01:43:09.445 28804-28811/com.roadraz.vcademy1 W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.088ms
03-25 01:43:09.839 28804-28837/com.roadraz.vcademy1 D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
03-25 01:43:09.859 28804-28804/com.roadraz.vcademy1 D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xab8027b0, tid 28804
03-25 01:43:10.115 28804-28811/com.roadraz.vcademy1 W/art: Suspending all threads took: 164.743ms
03-25 01:43:10.269 28804-28837/com.roadraz.vcademy1 I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
03-25 01:43:10.316 28804-28837/com.roadraz.vcademy1 W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-25 01:43:10.316 28804-28837/com.roadraz.vcademy1 W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xabfbe100, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-25 01:43:10.874 28804-28836/com.roadraz.vcademy1 W/MYAPP: org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@fed3d3f
03-25 01:43:10.875 28804-28836/com.roadraz.vcademy1 W/MYAPP: org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@fed3d3f
03-25 01:43:11.012 28804-28837/com.roadraz.vcademy1 W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-25 01:43:11.012 28804-28837/com.roadraz.vcademy1 W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xad7b4460, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-25 01:43:14.417 28804-28837/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb4057390
03-25 01:43:14.491 28804-28837/com.roadraz.vcademy1 W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-25 01:43:14.491 28804-28837/com.roadraz.vcademy1 W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xad7cc3a0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-25 01:43:16.438 28804-28837/com.roadraz.vcademy1 E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb4053dc0
```

Comment: debug it from the line no you saw at amdroid monitor
It might be coz you did sth like
`String s;
JsonObject jo =  s.getJSONObject();
`

Comment: I have uploaded the android monitor...please have a look and help me!!

Comment: You got error in your ListDrawer() method. In catch-Block write e.printStackTrace();
So that you'll get more detail on your exception.

May I see your json?

Answer (score 0):

try changing it to the following

```
//build hash set for list view
    public void ListDrawer() {
        List<Map<String, String>> facultyList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        try {
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
            JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("asdb");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonChildNode = new JSONObject(jsonMainNode.getString(i));
                String name = jsonChildNode.optString("name");
                String number = jsonChildNode.optString("roll_no");
                String outPut = name + "-" + number;
                facultyList.add(createFaculty("faculties",outPut));
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Toast.makeText(IT_Faculty.this, "Error...2" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter= new SimpleAdapter(IT_Faculty.this,facultyList,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,new String[]{"faculties"},new int[]{android.R.id.text1});
        listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
        Toast.makeText(IT_Faculty.this, "c", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```